# PHP for FOR LOOP

Tags: php, mysql

```
//....................


CREATE TABLE operation_tbl (
op_no INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
op_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
mtype VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
createby VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
date date(),
time time()
);


CREATE TABLE opbreak_tbl (
ob_no INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
style_no VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
createby VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
date date(),
time time()
);

CREATE TABLE op_opbreak_tbl (
ob_no INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
op_no INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
createby VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
date date(),
time time()
);
```

/* Above show tables structures */

```
//.................................................
<?php

$sql1="SELECT * FROM operation_tbl";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);



if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
include("dbconnection.php");

$sql3="INSERT INTO opbreak_tbl(style_no,createby,date,time) VALUES('$_POST[style_no]','$_SESSION[uname]','".date('Y-m-d h:m:s')."','".date('h:i:s',mktime(date('h')+5,date('i')+30,date('s')))."')";
if(mysql_query($sql3)){

$inid= mysql_insert_id();
```

/* get added Auto Increment value "ob_no" from $sql3 */

```
$checkbox1=$_POST['oid'];
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox1);$i++){
$sql2="INSERT INTO op_opbreak_tbl (ob_no,op_no,createby,date,time)       VALUES( '".$inid."','".$checkbox1[$i]."','$_SESSION[uname]','".date('Y-m-d h:m:s')."','".date('h:i:s',mktime(date('h')+5,date('i')+30,date('s')))."')";
}}
if (mysql_query($sql2)){

    $msg="Operation Break Down has been Added... ".$inid;  
     header("Location:operation brackdown.php?id=$msg");
    }else{
     $msg="Operation Brack Down has not been Added...".mysql_error();
     header("Location:operation brackdown.php?id=$msg");
    }


 }else{

 ?>

   <head>
</head>

<body>
<form id=operationbrack method="POST" action="<?php echo    $_SERVER['Adm/PHP_SELF']; ?>">

  <table>
 <tr>
 <th height="34" bgcolor="#999999"><div align="center"><strong>OPERATION NO</strong></div></th><th height="34" bgcolor="#999999"><div align="center"><strong>OPERATION NAME</strong></div></th>
<th bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong>ADD </strong></div>   </th>
  </tr>

<?php

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . $row1['op_no'] . "</td><td>" .       $row1['op_name'] . "</td><td><div align='center'>
  <input name='oid[]' type='checkbox' id='oid[]' value=".$row1['op_no']."    />
   </div>
   </td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  }


mysql_close($con);
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="3"><div align="center">
  <input type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Add to Operation  Brack Down" />
  </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

/*  when user click in submit button, i need to run $sql3 and get Auto       Incremet Value that generated for ob_no    , after that run FOR LOOP for     $sql2 to add all Checked values(op_no) with the "ob_no"
now only one checked value added by $sql2 need support to correct the FOR     LOOP in my scenario
*/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is extremely messy, it even contains missing closing `}`. Some places are also just illogical. I have restructured your code (I think nothing is missing):

```
<?php

include("dbconnection.php");
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM operation_tbl";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

if (!empty($_POST['Save']))
{
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO opbreak_tbl(style_no, createby, date, time) VALUES('$_POST[style_no]', '$_SESSION[uname]', '".date('Y-m-d h:m:s')."', '".date('h:i:s', mktime(date('h')+5, date('i')+30, date('s')))."')";
    if (mysql_query($sql3)) {
        $inid = mysql_insert_id(); 

        /* get added Auto Increment value "ob_no" from $sql3 */
        $checkbox1 = $_POST['oid'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($checkbox1); $i++) {
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO op_opbreak_tbl (ob_no,op_no,createby,date,time) VALUES('".$inid."', '".$checkbox1[$i]."', '$_SESSION[uname]', '".date('Y-m-d h:m:s')."', '".date('h:i:s', mktime(date('h')+5,date('i')+30, date('s')))."')";
            if (mysql_query($sql2)) {
                $msg = "Operation Break Down has been Added... ".$inid; 
            } else {
                $msg = "Operation Brack Down has not been Added...".mysql_error();
            }
        }
    }
    header("Location: operation brackdown.php?id=$msg");
} else {
?>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<form id="operationbrack" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['Adm/PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th height="34" bgcolor="#999999"><div align="center"><strong>OPERATION NO</strong></div></th>
            <th height="34" bgcolor="#999999"><div align="center"><strong>OPERATION NAME</strong></div></th>
            <th bgcolor="#999999"> <div align="center"><strong>ADD </strong></div></th>
        </tr>
    <?php
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row1['op_no'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row1['op_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><div align='center'><input name='oid[]' type='checkbox' id='oid[]' value=".$row1['op_no']."></div></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Add to Operation  Brack Down"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
mysql_close($con);
}
```

I didn't change all areas because there is too much of them. For example, MySQL API is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and is no longer maintained. You should switch to `MySQLi` or `PDO` API. You're also not escaping user input, therefore, you're vulnerable to SQL injection. There are more things that are not quite good but for now it's enough with what I have provided.

Should be good enough and it will execute as many queries as how many columns were selected.